# fill down formula using vba to set starting cell dynamic

Tags: vba, excel, sum, offset

```
lastRow44 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow3 = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Range("A" & LastRow3).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 11).Formula = "=Sum(M50:M" & lastRow44 & ")"
```

I am trying to modify vba code to be more dynamic. I would like to set sum calculation more dynamic. So  I am trying something like    `Range("A" & LastRow3).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 11).Formula = "=Sum(("M" & LastRow3).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 11) & lastRow44 & ")"`
to define starting cell as  M50 automatically. However it is not work as what I intended. Is any way to modify code to make sum calculation of starting cell dynamic?

Thank you!

Comment: The equation you're using for defining the .formula needs better quotation management.  ="=sum(M"&lastrow3&":X"&lastrow44&")".  That would be the first big step.

Comment: That X assumes the offset you want of +11 goes from M (13th letter) to X (24th letter).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
lastRow44 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow3 = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

to

```
lastRow44 = Sheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow3 = Worksheets("Temp").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with

```
Range("A" & LastRow3).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 11).Formula = _
"=Sum(("M" & LastRow3).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 11) & lastRow44 & ")"
```

What your formula is doing is first setting to the lastrow that you defined, and then searching downward (as if you hit CTRL + down-arrow). If this is not what you intend, try removing the ".END(xlDown" portion of both.

Lastly, if you know you are using an offset of 11, why not set it to use "M" instead of A, and simply not offset?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that:

```
lastRow44 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 50 To LastRow3
Range("A" & x).Formula = "=Sum(""M""" & x & "": M "" & lastRow44 & ")"
Next x
```